# spring httpinvokerserviceexporter must the client be on same framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-remoting

Sorry i'm new to spring and have a question about the httpinvokerserviceexporter. I had a rudimentary setup by following the tutorials:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="hello.htm">test_service</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean name="test_service" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="hellohttp.HelloServiceInterface" />
        <property name="service">
            <ref bean="helloService"></ref>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And just to test if I works: I run the url `http://localhost:8080/hello_spring/hello.htm` and got the following stacktrack from the glassfish server:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[hello_spring]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet hello_spring threw exception
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2298)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2767)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.<init>(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:64)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.CodebaseAwareObjectInputStream.<init>(CodebaseAwareObjectInputStream.java:97)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter.createObjectInputStream(RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.readRemoteInvocation(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.readRemoteInvocation(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Well, is this error caused by me using a browser instead of a spring enabled and java application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpInvokerServiceExporter` uses standard Java binary serialization to move the data from Java objects over the wire. This data can only be used by a Java client at the other end (and in this case, by a Spring Java client).  It's intended to be the server-end of a client-server setup.

You can't just point a browser at it, the browser will just see it as gibberish.

Comment: sorry something I don't understand, but if the its the client end of application that does not understand the data, why is the server producing error 500?

Comment: @goh: Because `HttpInvokerServiceExporter` cannot accept the sort of HTTP requests that a browser will send. It can only handle special requests posted by the client end of the Spring Remoting stuff.

Comment: ah... thanks @skaffman for the prompt reply.  will go test it out!